# Cleaning up innerHTML output

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

So I have been working on a rich-text editor that is really just a glorified contenteditable div. I was using .innerHTML to rip all the formatting for when I saved it, but now I have ran into the problem that I want to be able to have a fallback textbox for when contenteditable is not supported. (iOS) The output of innerHTML contains lots of unnecessary styles and I was wondering what is the best way to clean those out.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/aGPeS/

What is the best way to filter out the innerHTML output to the "cleaned-up" example?

EDIT: changed from google docs to jsfiddle

Comment: Can you show some of those styles here or on jsfiddle.net? The document is not accessible without a Google account

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for regular expressions for this one, you can implement those in javascript if you want or the server side scripting / programming language that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to process the output with a proper HTML parser. There are [pure Javascript solutions](http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/) or you can send it to server to process it with your favourite server side language.